# Determining whether a request is from the server or a client c#

Tags: c#, authentication, client-server, onactionexecuting

Is there a way to determine whether an `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)` request is coming from the server or client?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure this is completely correct, but the answer may be:

```
var requester = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer == null ? "client" : "server";
```

(I.e. if there is a referrer url, then it's a server request, if there isn't it's a client request)